# Batch export text files based on ID values of a data frame using R

Tags: r

I have a file with lat, long and hundreds of index values (I):

```
head(df2)
       lat      lon I Wp.ID      Date       
1 23.71413 90.67866 3 2867G 14-Jan-13      
2 23.71690 90.66534 3 2374J 12-Dec-12      
3 23.71701 90.66492 3 2377J 12-Dec-12      
4 23.71701 90.66565 4 2373J 12-Dec-12      
5 23.71712 90.66569 4 2372J 12-Dec-12
6 23.71712 90.66462 4 2378J 12-Dec-12 
... ...
... ...
```

If I want to select the data based on index (I); say for instance, I = 4 , I write it as:

```
Idx <- df2[df2$I == 4,]
```

then I can export it as:

```
write.table(Idx, file = "/Users/Idx4.txt",
          eol = "\n", na = "NA", row.names = FALSE)
```

Since there are more than 100 index values, I wanted to make a loop to write all files at once, but I'm not sure how to do it using R. Any idea to proceed??

Comment: you actually have to make the loop, there's no clever way (like vectorization) around that. So just use normal loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to achieve that but I prefer `plyr::l_ply`

```
require(plyr)
save_df <- function(index) {
    write.table(subset(df2, I == index),
                file = file.path("Users", paste0("Idx", index, ".txt")), 
                row.names = FALSE)
}

l_ply(df2$I, save_df)
```

Comment: nice but the process seems really slow!

Answer (score 0):

If you have ~100 index values and your data is not too large you can do this very simply:

```
fnames <- sort(unique(df2$I))
dfs <- split(df2, df2$I)
lapply(1:length(fnames), function (k) {
         write.table(dfs[[k]],
                     file=paste0("Users/", fnames[[k]], ".txt"),
                     row.names=FALSE)
         })
```

Comment: something is wrong with the bracket: r is throwing Error: unexpected '}' in: "write.table(dfs[[k]], ... ...

Comment: Did you replace the comment 'put your other arguments here' with the other arguments?

Comment: yap, I did incorporate row.names = FALSE